# multi-root workspace organization

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a complete noob to VSCode configurations and I'm trying to organize my sources repository properly.
My main concern is to have practical ways of sharing my VSCode setup, but without filling the repository with VSCode specific files. Meaning, if I have a multi-root kind of workspace, can I have a workspace file that defines all needs (intelisense, cmake, build and debug tasks)? Or each folder should always have .vscode directories, plus the workspace file itself?

What guidelines do you follow to organize your project tree?

Thanks in advance!